# How to create DSN for SQL Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, dsn

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using Microsoft.Win32;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


[DllImport("ODBCCP32.dll")]

private static extern bool SQLConfigDataSource(IntPtr parent, int request, string driver, string attributes);



namespace CopyDatabase
{

public partial class Synchronize : Form
{

    public Synchronize()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Synchronize_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server srv = new Server();
        String[] s = { "master", "tempdb", "model", "msdb", "Resource", "distribution" };

        foreach (Database database in srv.Databases)
        {
            int flag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(database.Name, s[i], true) == 0)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                cmbSource.Items.Add(database.Name);
                cmbDest.Items.Add(database.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string str = "SERVER=HOME\0DSN=MYDSN\0DESCRIPTION=MYDSNDESC\0DATABASE=DBServer\0TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES";
        SQLConfigDataSource((IntPtr)0, 4, "SQL Server",str);
    }
}
```

}

Reference :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/441811b9-c4e9-4d15-97a3-7b92d2c9f318

Can anybody help me remove the following errors??

> Error 1   Expected class, delegate,
>   enum, interface, or
>   struct    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Pavan\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\CopyDatabase\CopyDatabase\Synchronize.cs    17  23  CopyDatabase

.

> Error 2   The name 'SQLConfigDataSource'
>   does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Pavan\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\CopyDatabase\CopyDatabase\Synchronize.cs    67  13  CopyDatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the rest of your code for context, my WAG is that you didn't declare a class around the extern and click handler.

Comment: i have posted my program again. I havent implemented much, i just started with the WinForm where i have the requirement to assign DSN dynamically to the database say 'DBServer', how can i declare a class around extern and click handler?. Can you help me out??

Comment: Looks like your click handler is already in the class. Just move the your extern down about 10 lines so that it declared inside your Synchronize class.

Comment: i figured it out. i actually had to import the dll inside class. i declared with namespaces.Thanks.:)

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to dynamically create SQL Dsn just change this code to this structure--

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  
using Microsoft.Win32;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;   


namespace CopyDatabase 
{  
 public partial class Synchronize : Form 
 {      
   [DllImport("ODBCCP32.dll")]  
   private static extern bool SQLConfigDataSource(IntPtr parent, int request, string
   driver, string attributes);    

   public Synchronize()     
   {         
     InitializeComponent();     
   }      

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
   {        
     string str  = "SERVER=HOME\0DSN=MYDSN\0DESCRIPTION=MYDSNDESC\0DATABASE=DBServer\0TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES";         
SQLConfigDataSource((IntPtr)0, 4, "SQL Server",str);     
   } 
  }
```