# How to Use SQLConfigDataSource in a Visual Studio 2012 C# Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, odbc

I want to create a User DSN programmatically. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334939/how-do-i-create-an-odbc-dsn-entry-using-c) and similar SO questions; trolled the MSDN forums; and looked in several other places, to find out how to make SQLConfigDataSource work. In the SO post I've linked above, I see `SQLConfigDataSourceW` is referenced, but cannot find a reference to that.

I want to use `SQLConfigDataSource` or a similar function in a Visual Studio 2012 C# project, and do not know what should be included in my .cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I've looked at System.Data.Odbc and SQLConfigDataSource appears not to be part of that.
I believe the ODBC drivers are installed on my workstation. Other than using a .reg file or manually creating a DSN, what other steps can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Other than using a .reg file or manually creating a DSN, what other steps can I try to create a User DSN programmatically?**

You could use the [ODBCCONF.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388579(v=vs.85).aspx), a command-line tool that allows you to configure ODBC drivers and data source names. It uses the SQLConfigDataSource function. However, that is such old technology and Microsoft warns:

> ODBCCONF.exe will be removed in a future version of Windows Data
>   Access Components. Avoid using this feature, and plan to modify
>   applications that currently use this feature.

I am not sure what impact decommissioning ODBCCONF.exe will have on `SQLConfigDataSource` but it doesn't look good. Hence one of the best way forward is to use the recommended PowerShell commands to manage drivers and data sources, here is the list of [Windows Data Access Components PowerShell Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134064(v=vs.85).aspx).

You just run cmdlets like [Add-OdbcDsn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771022.aspx):

```
Add-OdbcDsn [-Name] <String> -DriverName <String> -DsnType <String> [-AsJob] [-CimSession <CimSession> ] [-PassThru] [-Platform <String> ] [-SetPropertyValue <String> ] [-ThrottleLimit <Int32> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

eg:

> PS C:> Add-OdbcDsn -Name "MyPayroll" -DriverName "SQL Server Native
>   Client 10.0" -DsnType "System" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=MyServer",
>   "Trusted_Connection=Yes", "Database=Payroll")

<sub>I'm guessing you already know or can easily find out how to execute these powershell commands from in C#.</sub>

---

Unfortunately the [above powershell commands are for Windows 8 and above](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/data/archive/2012/04/06/odbc-dsn-management-in-the-next-release-of-windows-code-named-windows-8-and-windows-server-8.aspx).

For Windows 7 and below you could either:
a) use [ODBCCONF.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388579(v=vs.85).aspx)
b) write to the registry directly in C#
c) use **[the SQLConfigDataSource function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5031879/495455)**, or
d) use a Powershell script that works for Windows 7:

```
PS C:\> Add-ODBCconnection2HKCU.ps1
```

Here is the add-ODBCconnection2HKCU.ps1:

```
## Add to the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" - registry ODBC update Add a ODBC Connection as a User DSN tab
$HKCUaddpath = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\LocalDeveloper"
cd HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\LocalDeveloper
md LocalDeveloper
Set-ItemProperty -path $HKCUaddpath -name Database -value "Developer"
Set-ItemProperty -path $HKCUaddpath -name Description -value "Local Developer database"
Set-ItemProperty -path $HKCUaddpath -name Driver -value "C:\Windows\System32\SQLSRV32.dll"
Set-ItemProperty -path $HKCUaddpath -name LastUser -value ""
Set-ItemProperty -path $HKCUaddpath -name Server -value "Max-PCWIN1"
Set-ItemProperty -path $HKCUaddpath -name Trusted_Connection -value "Yes"

## This is needed for this ODBC connection to show in the "ODBC Administator" application
cd HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\'ODBC Data Sources'
Set-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\'ODBC Data Sources' -name LocalDeveloper -value "SQL Server"
```

REF: http://maxt2posh.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/powershell-working-with-odbc-dsn-connection/

Comment: In the absense of Windows 8 -- we're on Windows 7 -- is there an older command that will accomplish the same thing? I've been looking for this out on MSDN's site, and the command appears to be new. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help and its a shame about the windows 8 limitation so I added some more research for the Windows 7 scenario.